# ERROR: MethodError: 'length' has no method matching length(::Filter{Function,Tuple{...}})

Tags: filter, tuples, list-comprehension, julia

I read in [here](https://github.com/chrisvoncsefalvay/learn-julia-the-hard-way/blob/master/_chapters/07-ex4.md#filtering) that you can't `filter!` a tuple since it is immutable, but you do can `filter` it. Then, why is it that this gives me Error?

```
a = tuple([collect(1:10)]...)
b = [x for x in filter(y -> y % 2 == 0, a)]
ERROR: MethodError: `length` has no method matching length(::Filter{Function,Tuple{Int64}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that you cannot filter it, what happens is that `length` (which is called by the list comprehension) has no method (yet, at least) for what `filter` returns, which is an iterable but of type `Filter`. You can wrap the filter in `collect`, or better yet, simplify the whole operation:

```
a = tuple(collect(1:10)...)
b1 = [x for x in collect(filter(y -> y % 2 == 0, a))]
b2 = collect(filter(y -> y % 2 == 0, a))
```

Comment: A filter iterator cannot have a length, You can look at the example `` filter(x->rand()<0.5,a) `` which is a filter which throws away elements with probability 0.5, so the number of elements is random